# Syntax Highlighter Numbering off and Closing List<Object> "tags"

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-highlighting

This is kind of weird. I'm trying to get my code up on my website using [Syntax Highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/). I've come up against two weird problems.
1 - Code lines are off, in some cases worse than others
2 - Syntax Highlighter wants to close what it thinks are xml / html tags. If you go to the following link and look at the numbers and the bottom of the screen, you'll know what I mean.

http://kentcdodds.com/projectsamples/BankGUI/GUI.html

I'm not sure what's wrong. But I also just noticed it changed my capital `S` on `String` to a lower case `s`. I'm developing a program in Java to add all the html necessary before and after each of my .java files for my school projects this last year so I can put the code up for the world to see and hopefully help. So if I could get some help from someone with this Syntax Highlighter problem, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though there is no real solution using this technology. So the best I can do is say hard-code changes for when String goes to lowercase and don't use line numbers. I'm sorry if this isn't helpful for people in the future. You might try one of [these alternatives](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/11-syntax-highlighters-to-beautify-code-presentation/).